# Building rethinkdb from source on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, rethinkdb

I am trying to build rethinkdb from source and hitting on this error:

```
npm WARN engine amdefine@0.1.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.4.2"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.11.3"})
npm WARN engine mime-db@1.13.0: wanted: {"node":">= 0.6"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.11.3"})
npm http fetch 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-property/-/is-property-1.0.2.tgz
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-30-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "--userconfig" "/home/myth/rethinkdb/mk/support/config/npm.conf" "--cache" "/home/myth/rethinkdb/external/npm_cache-2cOLXsUU" "--cache" "/home/myth/rethinkdb/external/admin-deps_2.0.3.fetch-2Suk269g/npm-cache" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.13.0-pre
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: vinyl-fs@0.3.13
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":">= 0.10"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"2.11.3","node":"0.13.0-pre"}

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/myth/rethinkdb/external/admin-deps_2.0.3.fetch-bcJwskoE/npm-debug.log

Full error log: ./build/external/admin-deps_2.0.3_fetch.log
make[1]: *** [external/admin-deps_2.0.3] Error 1
make: *** [make] Error 2
```

Seems like an appropriate version of npm is missing. Which version do I need?
How should I diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is not RethinkDB, but the `vinyl-fs` (an npm module) which doesn't seem to like the fact that you're using a version of node with `-pre`. Perhaps you can try installing [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and using 0.12 to install RethinKDB?